# Limiting max allowed length of input in the <div></div> element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable, maxlength

I would like to limit the max length of the possible input in a `div` element (it is a search box) to a specific value (ex., 256). However, it seems that there's no such property on the `div` elements, and if I switch it to `input` instead of `div`, I had the following error:

> Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Setting it to `textarea` haven't work as expected and was just showing `[object object]`. I suspect that `textarea` elements just don't work with `ContentEditable`.

What could be a workaround here in order to limit the possible length of input in that `div` to 256?

Code:

```js
export class TagInput extends React.Component<TagInputProps, TagInputState> {
  render() {
    window.setTimeout(() => this.handleFocus(), 100);
    return (
      <divclassName="tag-input-border" onClick={this.handleInputClick}>
        {this.props.tags.map(t => (
          <div
            key={t.name}
            className={getClasses(t)}
            onClick={(e) => this.handleTagClick(t.name, e)}
          >
            {t.name !== '' && <span>{t.label + ':'}</span> }
            <ContentEditable
              html={he.encode(t.value)}
              onKeyUp={(e) => this.handleKeyUp(t.name, e)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(t.name, e)}
              onChange={(e) => this.handleContentChange(t.name, e.target.value)}
              tagName="span"
              className="tag-editable"
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where `ContentEditable` comes from

Comment: So you need an input box where the user can type something, and the max char limit is 250 is that what you are looking

Comment: As I understand `ContentEditable` is responsible for the getting input .  So , cannot u just put a check in `handleContentChange` so that if the `e.target.value` has `length` more than 256 , u just dont accept it .

Comment: @ColouredPanda it is a separate library, react-contenteditable

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS it seems to be not working with input because I'm passing some children elements to it from contenteditable and it brings up an error

Comment: @AnkushVerma in my case ContentEditable is only used for tags that are being inserted into that main div element. There can be multiple tags and there's no max length specs for them. I would like to limit the max input for this whole div, in which they are all being wrapped as children